# Back to Home Fragment when I press on back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

My MainActivity contains 4 fragments. My home-fragment is FragmentA. When I press on back button at FragmentB,C or D, I have to return back to FragmentA. If I am on FragmentA and press back button, I have to `moveTasktoBack()`.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `I have to moveTasktoBack().` you mean quit the application like you normally would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330313/how-to-have-android-action-bar-back-button-return-to-fragment)

Just change it so it returns to your home fragment. In the future try to search before you ask, more often than not the answer already exists.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When You replacing the fragment from home fragment and form A then use like this Like

```
FragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
```

then after that paste this line

```
FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
```

from B and C don't use

```
FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(backStateName);
```